# According to the Catholic Church, how does the creation and imposition of 1752 canon laws lend to and exemplify the simplicity that is in Christ?

Tags: catholicism, canon-law

According to the Catholic Church, how does the creation and imposition of 1752 canon laws lend to and exemplify the simplicity that is in Christ?

I've asked this question and had it closed as 'opinion-based' based on my attempt to ask it within the context of an exposition of "simplicity in Christ".  I then attempted an edit to re-open the question by removing the opinion-based content (the exposition I provided).  In that edit I supplied a referenced definition of 'simplicity' rather than the exposition I had put together from a wide range of Scriptures.  Objection was made to that referenced definition as well.

I then deleted the closed, edited, and waiting for review question and attempted to simply ask the title question stripped of any and all additional commentary and received a message that it did not meet the quality standards of the site:

```
A clear title.
A reasonable explanation of what your question is. Add as much detail as you can.
Any background research you've tried but wasn't enough to solve your problem.
Correct use of English spelling and grammar to the best of your ability.
```

Every attempt I have made to edit this question in response to comments so that it can remain open, meet the above requirements, and gather answers has, instead, gathered more and different opposition.  I would like to simply ask the following:

According to the Catholic Church, how does the creation and imposition of 1752 canon laws lend to and exemplify the simplicity that is in Christ?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148493/discussion-on-question-by-mike-borden-according-to-the-catholic-church-how-does); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.